# Matched value from input with Array object

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to match the value of user input with an array object and then return the same result to the table

Here is my code

```
function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;

    var myList = dataDummy;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");

    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    console.log(filter);
    table = document.getElementById("our-table");
    tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    for (i = 0; i <  myList.length; i++) {
        td = (myList[i].nama);
        console.log(myList[i].nama);
        // td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[3];
        if (td) {
            txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
            if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                tr[i].style.display = "";
            } else {
                tr[i].style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

here is the display when i search on the HTML
[image]

can someone tell me where did i do wrong here, the table supposed to show the same name with the input only, but it didn't works

Comment: What is `txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText` supposed to do? `td` is the boolean result from `td = (filter == myList[i].nama);`

Comment: get the value of the td, i've fix my question

Comment: It still makes no sense. `td` is now the name from the `myList` array, not a DOM element with `textContent`.